# Masterpage + updatepanel on child page

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages

So I have a masterpage with a login that is in an update panel.  I have a child page that has a literal control that should update when the login updates.  What it doesn't do is reload the method I use to generate the content for that literal when it posts back.  I tried to call the method on the child page from the master page once you click log in, but I get an error that the literal control cannot be found (because it exists on the child page not the master page).  How would I reference that control in the masterpage to pass it to my method?

Answer (score 0):

The article below shows how the control tree works with MasterPages and how to reference different controls at different levels of the control tree.

[ASP.Net 2.0 - Master Pages: Tips, Tricks, and Traps](http://odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx)

Comment: Well none of that worked, still couldn't find the control.  The issues is more like when the child page updatepanel reloads, it doesn't do a full postback to refresh the data unless I hit reload.  It checks for a session variable set after you log in.  Perhaps the session variable gets set after the method that controls the child page content is fired?

Answer (score 0):

So the scenario is that you have an update panel on the child page that when triggered doesn't update/refresh your lets say, label which is in your header on your master page.

What you do is, in the code behind of your master page create a function that changes the value of the label.

Include an update panel on the master page for the label, which is triggered by the textchanged event etc.

Now, in your child page code behind or your let say, button click event, call upon the function that exists in the master page and send the needed value in the parenthesis.

**C#:**

```
((MyMaster)this.Page.Master).ShowMessage(text);
```

**VB.NET:**

```
DirectCast(Me.Page.Master, MyMaster).ShowMessage(text)
```

This should update the label with the correct value whilst triggering the update panel on the master page and thus refreshing your label as well.

I'm about to try this now for myself, wish me luck. :D